# How to Get consumer key and access token for Twitter from java code

Tags: java, twitter

I have a page which will redirect to user to twitter account, after entering username and password it should generate all the tokens required to twitter api from Java code and redirect back to my web page. Till now I am doing it manually

Comment: write code, compile it, run it

Comment: I am using twitter4j api for all my work. I just need to add a functionality where user does not have to enter his access token manualy to the system. I should be able to get it by code. I don't have refrence. Do you have any?

Comment: Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions here. Please be aware that we do not provide from-scratch coding service here. Please show us what you've tried already, how it failed and we might be able to help.